# A particular music from the movie "Sing"

Tags: electronic-music

I was wondering about a song in the movie - Sing.

It is the part when the d=singing team was selected and suddenly the bunnies come and play a music (around 22 minutes of the start of the movie).

Does anyone know the song or music?

Comment: Please add a link to the requested song, as we don't have the movie, we won't be able to help you. Have you checked the movie credits?

Comment: Thank you @Bebs , I checked the credits and it helped me!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the song is in this link -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLi_cf7Z9jQ

"Kira Kira Killer".

Thanks Bebs for the solution to check the credits of the movie.